# How to load training labels as per the training images split?

Tags: python

I want to have my training labels separate from my test labels, when I try to do it according to the filenames in my train split that does not work as the labels keep duplicating for
each image which is not correct. My training data consists of 6660 images and I want to have the labels according to the filenames in the set.

For example, the label of my first image should be [219, 173, 247, 188] but instead I get duplicates of the same label.
[image]

My training set consists of 6660 images which have unique bounding box dimensions.

The code below just stores the images into the training_data list.

```
training_data = []
for img in os.listdir(train_path):
    pic = cv2.imread(os.path.join(train_path, img))
    training_data.append(pic)
```

The code below checks if the image filename (filenames) exists in the training set then adds the respective label to training_labels list. This causes duplication of the same bounding box dimensions.

```
training_labels = []
for i in range(len(training_data)):
    for j in range(len(filenames)):
        if filenames[j] == img:
            training_labels.append(label_dimensions_scaled[j])
```

Answer (score 0):

I would, first of all, recommend you not loop through booth arrays. This is not performant. Try looping through the images and changing the image extension to .txt (if your labels are in .txt format). Then you can quickly search for the desired label. This could look like the following:

```
training_labels = []
for img in os.listdir(train_path):
    label_name = os.path.splitext(img)[0] + '.txt'
    label_path = os.path.join(<path to you label directory>, label_name)

    if os.path.exists(label_path): 
       training_labels.append(label_name)
```